# TI SensorTag Accelerometer service not advertising

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ios-bluetooth

I'm working with the TI SensorTag in the Swift environment and am able to connect, but only the UUIDs for temperature, humidity and barometric pressure advertise as services, but not the magnetic, gyro and accel sensors.  Are the examples of getting the sensor to advertise these services using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. What happened with me was that the battery was going flat and the first thing to stop working was the gyro-acc-mag. What was confusing was that the Lux, temperature and other sensors all worked fine.

I do my dev work now with the tag powered via USB. Alternatively you could replace your battery every now and then?

Comment: Thanks - this is a brand new unit, but it could be the battery.

Comment: Let me know if that makes a difference. I got a few tags, some went flat really early on, others lasted a bit longer.

Comment: Just put in a new battery - no change.   But, I did update to firmware 1.12 (Jun 23 2015), and service UUID AA80 seems to include gyro, mag and accel per the iPhone SensorTag app.  There appears to be no longer AA30, AA50 and AA10 (so those service UUIDs are not advertised).   Is there an updated wiki to reflect this change in services and the data format?  That is certainly not obvious on the TI site.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have the latest Sensortag (CC2650) but that you are using a library that is specific for the original Sensortag?

For a list of the CC2650 services, the GATT table can be found at the bottom of this page: http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag2015/tearDown.html

The Node Sensortag is also quite useful, it supports both and shows the differences: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-sensortag/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the IBM wearables SDK to connect to sensorTag, it it written in swift and has easy API for working with all the sensors.

Take a look:
http://wearables.mybluemix.net/

Code:
https://github.com/ibm-wearables-sdk-for-mobile/ibm-wearables-swift-sdk

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the change in UUID's.  The new 2650 uses the MPU-9250 and you have to write your Swift code with AA80-AA83 for the UUID for Gyro + Accelerometer + Compass.  Vs the past code that used a unique UUID for each of those 3 sensors.

Comment: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide#Sensors
The movement sensor used on the SensprTag is MPU9250 from InvenSense.

Movement
Type UUID Access Size (bytes) Description
Data AA81* R/N 18 GyroX[0:7], GyroX[8:15], GyroY[0:7],